# How to recognise smart clients GIS/WISPr

Tags: wifi, roaming, wispr

How to detect devices seeking http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WISPr XML feed?

I am guessing there should be some sort of the request that is standardised. Though, I managed to uncover that iPass itself is passing `iPassConnect` rather than anything that would contain WISPr in it.

Answer (score 0):

Wispr and GIS are different protocol, today, over 20 access gateways support the GIS with iPass:

- Cisco BBSM
- Nomadix USGII/HSG/AG2000
- Aptilo Mobile Access Server
- ANTLabs ezXcess Servers
- Pronto Hotspot Controller
- ServiceFactory Orbyte Wireless System
- Colubris CN3000
- Wificom SAB Gateway
- Nokia P022 Acccess Controller
- Unitech Intelligate
- Gemtek Systems G­6000 Public Access Controller
- Mikrotik RouterOS Hotspot system

More information here http://www.pcca.org/standards/architecture/ipass_pwlan.pdf

Comment: Link-only answers are not expected here. Please write the crucial part from the link, not just post the link